# how to include extra package in ansible?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, glusterfs

for example, want to use [gluster_volume module](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/gluster_volume_module.html).

with ansible 2.1 I get

> 'gluster_volume' is not a valid attribute for a Play.

How do I "include" it in my ansible?

```
---
  - name: create gluster volume
    hosts: all
    gluster_volume: state=present name=test1 bricks=/bricks/brick1/g1 rebalance=yes
    run_once: true
```

Comment: Please take a look at Ansible Playbook basics. You should use modules as `tasks` items.

Comment: Note an answer has been provided. Does it suit you? If so, accept. If not, leave a comment.

Comment: thanks, will try that soon..

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

```
---
  - name: create gluster volume
    hosts: all
    tasks:
      - gluster_volume: state=present name=test1 bricks=/bricks/brick1/g1 rebalance=yes
        run_once: true
```